# Does QnAMaker learn from the answers, or just from the questions?

Tags: azure-qna-maker

What would happen if I removed all answers from a QnAMaker knowledgebase and replaced them with IDs that mapped to the answers in a separate database? Would QnAMaker continue to return the same response (now as an ID)?

Asked another way: does the content of the answers affect the response? Or is QnAMaker basing its response entirely on the questions?

Answer (score 0):

> does the content of the answers affect the response? Or is QnAMaker basing its response entirely on the questions?

**Yes, QnA Maker learns from both, the question and the answer.**

You can test that easily with having just a URL as the answer. Your results will be bad and question is more likely matched to another pair until you add some meta data text to the link of the image (fitting the question) and re-train QnA again.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Please could you share link(s) to documentation that talks about these aspects?